# Question related to layout and margin of text in XSL

Tags: css

My other question about layout the text correctly on the webpage. I would like to write RSS code and then use XSL to format the RSS into HTML
My question:

Why the text of the ITEM DESCRIPTION run out of the margin of the webpage? HOw to force that piece of text maintain inside the margin?
[Run out of margin http://i40.photobucket.com/albums/e236/ngquochung86/somemargin.jpg](http://i40.photobucket.com/albums/e236/ngquochung86/somemargin.jpg)

My XML CODE:

```
<channel>
 .......
  <description>
   CHANNEL DESCRIPTION: Website of New York Times
  </description>
  <item>
    <title>
      ITEM TITLE:YouTube and Universal to Create a Hub for Music
    </title>
    <link>
     <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2009/04/10/technology/internet/10google.html?ref=technology"/>
    </link>
    <description>
     CHANNEL DESCRIPTION: The agreement is an effort by YouTube, which is owned by Google, to put more professionally produced content in front of its huge audience, and in turn, earn more money from advertising.
    </description>
  </item>
```

My XSL code:

```
<span class="channelDescription"> <xsl:value-of select="channel/description"/></span>
           <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
              <span class="itemTitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></span>
              <span class="itemLink"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></span>
              <span class="itemDescription"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></span>
           </xsl:for-each>
```

Would you please help me? Thank you

Comment: This is really a css question.  Its easy enough to see that simple HTML generated and that takes XSL out of the equation.  However you don't show us your CSS that is used to format the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Like AnthonyWJones said, this seems like a CSS/HTML question. Once you use XSLT to transform the RSS feed into HTML, it is simply treated (and thus rendered) as a standard HTML document.

My best guess at this point is that you need to put a container (a block level element such as **<DIV>**) around the description (or the whole document) and specify a width for it that is within the dimensions of the display using CSS.

So something like this should work:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width: 90%;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    // Your XSL code
</div>
```